# How to use CallerMemberName in a CLS compliant assembly

Tags: c#-6.0, default-parameters, cls-compliant

I have used the `CallerMemberName` attribute in a class's implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` as described on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

However, using default parameters is not CLS compliant. But `CallerMemberName` can only be used with parameters that have default values... Is there a commonly used way to solve this inconsistency without having to call the notify method with a hard-coded string argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simply removed the `CallerMemberName` attribute and the default parameter value, meaning the parameter is no longer optional, so the method signature becomes:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
```

Then it is a small (enough) change to call it with the `nameof` operator providing the string argument:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FooProperty));
```

This seems to work quite well.

I will leave the question open for a little while however as others may have better ways, or suggest problems with this solution.